# "expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given"

Tags: php

I think I may have a Heisenbug on my hands. My code so far looks like this:

```
$enc = $_REQUEST['l'];
$filename = DecryptString($enc);

echo $filename;  //Displays: uploads/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3


if (is_dir($filename))  //Gives the error: "Warning: is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given"
{

    Download($filename);
}
```

However, if I take what as echo'ed earlier, which was `uploads/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3`, and run `is_dir("uploads/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3")`, it returns as expected.

So if I pass the variable into `is_dir`, it fails, but if I pass the value of the variable it works. What's the catch?

Comment: check the permissions on your directory? If the apache user can't read it, is_dir will likely fail

Answer (score 2):

`DecryptString()` is returning a string with NULs (`\0`) at the end.

Make sure you trim them off before trying to use the value.

You can trim the NULL character with `$enc = trim($enc);`